# Why thread_info should be the first element in task_struct?

Tags: c, linux, process, linux-kernel

When reading Linux kernel source code, I find one thing makes me confused.

In `task_struct`, it says like this

```
struct task_struct {
#ifdef CONFIG_THREAD_INFO_IN_TASK
    /*
     * For reasons of header soup (see current_thread_info()), this
     * must be the first element of task_struct.
     */
    struct thread_info      thread_info;
#endif

...
};
```

The complete code is [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.7-rc1/source/include/linux/sched.h#L632), can you tell me why this must be the first element in `task_struct`?

Comment: https://lwn.net/Articles/700615/

Comment: @Maxim Egorushkin The website you showed tells some interest thing, but there is no relation with why it should be the first element.

Comment: `#define current_thread_info() ((struct thread_info *)current)` [Git blame](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/c65eacbe290b8141554c71b2c94489e73ade8c8d) is also super helpful.

Comment: But isn't. I _think_ that is because `current_thread_info` is visible before `struct task_struct` is declared, so it's an incomplete type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After searching many books, websites and debugging the Linux kernel, I understand the design of `thread_info` and I get to know why it must be the first element in `task_struct`.

Firstly, we need to understand [Linux kernel stack](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/x86/kernel-stacks.html).

Then, we come to the core : we need to get to kernel stack by `task_struct` some time, and we need to get to `task_struct` by kernel stack some time. So we must have some way to do it.

#### 1. `task_struct` to kernel stack

It is easy to use `stack` like below

```
static inline void *task_stack_page(const struct task_struct *task)
{
  return task->stack;
}
```

What's more, we can get to `pt_regs` by `task_pt_regs(task)`

#### 2.kernel stack to `task_struct`

Here is the use of `thread_info`.
Let me put two version here

```
struct thread_info {
  struct task_struct  *task;    /* main task structure */
  __u32      flags;    /* low level flags */
  __u32      status;    /* thread synchronous flags */
  __u32      cpu;    /* current CPU */
  mm_segment_t    addr_limit;
  unsigned int    sig_on_uaccess_error:1;
  unsigned int    uaccess_err:1;  /* uaccess failed */
};


struct thread_info {
  unsigned long flags;          /* low level flags */
  unsigned long status;    /* thread synchronous flags */    
};
```

The first one is the old version, it includes `task_struct`, from which we can go straightly to `task_struct`. But it costs too much to strore it, so the new version delete all.

In the old version, we have this function to get it.

```
static inline struct thread_info *current_thread_info(void)
{
  return (struct thread_info *)(current_top_of_stack() - THREAD_SIZE);
}
```

But how can we get to `task_struct` by the new version?

It is because we use a new `current_thread_info`

```
#include <asm/current.h>
#define current_thread_info() ((struct thread_info *)current)
#endif
```

The current is defined below

```
struct task_struct;

DECLARE_PER_CPU(struct task_struct *, current_task);

static __always_inline struct task_struct *get_current(void)
{
  return this_cpu_read_stable(current_task);
}

#define current get_current
```

That is to say, we have `task_struct` from per cpu.

Here is the last part of the source code we show

```
DEFINE_PER_CPU(struct task_struct *, current_task) = &init_task;

......

__visible __notrace_funcgraph struct task_struct *
__switch_to(struct task_struct *prev_p, struct task_struct *next_p)
{
......
this_cpu_write(current_task, next_p);
......
return prev_p;
}


...

#define this_cpu_read_stable(var)       percpu_stable_op("mov", var)
```

By this way, we can get `task_struct` easily.

Answer (score 4):

The comment says:

```
    /*
     * For reasons of header soup (see current_thread_info()), this
     * must be the first element of task_struct.
     */
    struct thread_info      thread_info;
```

And then `<linux/thread_info.h>`:

```
/*
 * For CONFIG_THREAD_INFO_IN_TASK kernels we need <asm/current.h> for the
 * definition of current, but for !CONFIG_THREAD_INFO_IN_TASK kernels,
 * including <asm/current.h> can cause a circular dependency on some platforms.
 */
#include <asm/current.h>
#define current_thread_info() ((struct thread_info *)current)
#endif
```

In other words, `<linux/thread_info.h>` cannot include `<linux/sched.h>`, where `task_struct` is defined, so that it cannot access its members. However, it can cast a `task_struct*` to the pointer to its first member ([C and C++ aliasing rules explicitly allow that](https://gist.github.com/shafik/848ae25ee209f698763cffee272a58f8#what-does-the-c11-standard-say)), which is `struct thread_info*`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. It is close to my question and it really help me a lot. After your help, I get the clear and complete answer by myself.